# Как правильно вызвать макрос в макросе

Tags: c, макросы, препроцессор

Мне необходимо бъеденить несколько передаваемых в макрос параметров, в один целый, для этого есть 2 макроса, `string_join` и `helper_name` *(префиксы опустил)*.

Но когда макрос должен развернуться к примеру с таким вызовом:
`KODIK_DEFINE_STRUCT(api);`

Ожидаемый мной разворот:

```
typedef struct __kodik_api_s kodik_api_t;
```

Но на деле, я получаю вот такой вывод:

```
 ../src/../include/kodik/kodik.h:50:94: error: expected ')' before ',' token
    50 | #   define __kodik_helper_name__(X, Y) __kodik_string_join__( kodik_, __kodik_string_join__(X, Y) )
       |                                                                                              ^
 ../src/../include/kodik/kodik.h:46:45: note: in definition of macro '__kodik_string_join__'
    46 | #   define __kodik_string_join__(X, Y) X ## Y
       |                                             ^
 ../src/../include/kodik/kodik.h:54:53: note: in expansion of macro '__kodik_helper_name__'
    54 | #   define KODIK_DEFINE_STRUCT(NAME) typedef struct __kodik_helper_name__(NAME, _s) __kodik_helper_name__(NAME, _t)
       |                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 ../src/main.c:3:1: note: in expansion of macro 'KODIK_DEFINE_STRUCT'
     3 | KODIK_DEFINE_STRUCT(api);
       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Как это можно исправить что бы вызываемый в макросе макрос был развернут?

```c
#ifndef __kodik_string_join__
#   define __kodik_string_join__(X, Y) X ## Y
#endif // !__kodik_string_join__

#ifndef __kodik_helper_name__
#   define __kodik_helper_name__(X, Y) __kodik_string_join__(kodik_, __kodik_string_join__(X, Y))
#endif // !__kodik_helper_name__

#ifndef KODIK_DEFINE_STRUCT
#   define KODIK_DEFINE_STRUCT(NAME) typedef struct __kodik_helper_name__(NAME, _s) __kodik_helper_name__(NAME, _t)
#endif // !KODIK_DEFINE_STRUCT

#ifndef KODIK_DECLARE_STRUCT
#   define KODIK_DECLARE_STRUCT(NAME) struct __kodik_helper_name__(NAME, _s)
#endif // !KODIK_DECLARE_STRUCT
```

Comment: `#   define __kodik_helper_name__(X, Y) __kodik_string_join__(kodik_, X ## Y )`

Comment: Идентификаторы, начинающиеся с двух подчеркиваний, являются зарезервированными.

Comment: Разжевал вам макросы, почитайте ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый подход обработки макроса с аргументами `( XValue, YValue )` :

```
__kodik_string_join__(kodik_, __kodik_string_join__(X, Y))
```

приведёт к добавлению приставки к самому имени макроса и замене всех аргументов :

```
kodik___kodik_string_join__(XValue, YValue)
```

Второй макрос `__kodik_string_join__` не обрабатывается. Вам проще не использовать лишние макросы, а сделать всё напрямую.

```
#   define __kodik_helper_name__(X, Y) kodik_ ## X ## Y
```

**P.S.**
Макросы с преобразованиями в строку `#` и макросы со слияниями `##` в своих аргументах берут только значения. Без обработки других макросов в аргументах. Чтобы слить `##` аргументы, полученные с помощью других макросов нужно погрузить аргументы в другой макрос, как предлагает **HolyBlackCat**.

Тест :

```
// gcc -E macroexp2.c
# define  MACRO0  macro0
# define  MACRO1(X,Y) macro1 X Y
# define  MACRO2(X,Y) macro2 X ## Y
# define  MACRO5(X,Y) macro5 MACRO2(X,Y)
# define  MACRO3(X) macro3 X
# define  MACRO4(X) macro4 # X
# define  MACRO6(X) macro6 MACRO4(X)

MACRO1(MACRO1(2+2,a+b),MACRO1(3+3,c+d))
MACRO1(MACRO2(2+2,a+b),MACRO2(3+3,c+d))
MACRO2(MACRO0,MACRO1(3+3,c+d))
MACRO2(MACRO0,MACRO2(3+3,c+d))
MACRO5(MACRO5(2+2,a+b),MACRO5(3+3,c+d))

MACRO3(MACRO3(3+3))
MACRO3(MACRO4(3+4))
MACRO4(MACRO3(4+3))
MACRO4(MACRO4(4+4))
MACRO6(MACRO6(6+6))
```

Результат :

```
macro1 macro1 2+2 a+b macro1 3+3 c+d
macro1 macro2 2+2a +b macro2 3+3c +d
macro2 MACRO0MACRO1(3+3,c+d)
macro2 MACRO0MACRO2(3+3,c+d)
macro5 macro2 macro5 macro2 2+2a +bmacro5 macro2 3+3c +d

macro3 macro3 3+3
macro3 macro4 "3+4"
macro4 "MACRO3(4+3)"
macro4 "MACRO4(4+4)"
macro6 macro4 "macro6 macro4 \"6+6\""
```

Comment: Жаль что нельзя делать так как я показал... Так очень даже удобно было бы =)

Answer (score 2):

Все потому, что `__kodik_string_join__` плохо написан. Он не раскрывает макросы в своих параметрах, и ничем не лучше `##`.

Если обернуть `##` во вложенный макрос:

```
#define __kodik_string_join__(X, Y) __kodik_string_join__0(X, Y)
#define __kodik_string_join__0(X, Y) X ## Y
```

То `__kodik_string_join__` начнет раскрывать макросы в параметрах, и все заработает.

Comment: Можно поподробнее? :)

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Препроцессор_Си#Пример_раскрытия_макроопределения

Comment: @ヒミコ Я бы просто запомнил этот паттерн. Можно еще вот тут посмотреть: http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.replace

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Спасибо =)